# linking a website with Navlink Router and Switch Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

Here is my code
`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
 <>
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
</>,
document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

my`App.js`

```
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
import "../node_modules/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import MainGet from "./getStart/MainGet";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MainGet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my `MainGet.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import GetStartedPage from "./GetStartedPage";
import Login from "./Login";
import Signup from "./Signup";
import DoctorShow from "../DoctorSidebar/DoctorShow";
import PatientShow from "../PatientSidebar/PatientShow";

const MainGet = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={GetStartedPage}></Route>
      <Route path="/Login" component={Login}></Route>
      <Route path="/Signup" component={Signup}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/DoctorShow" component={DoctorShow}></Route>
      <Route path="/PatientShow" component={PatientShow}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default MainGet;
```

my `DoctorShow.js`

```
import React from "react";
import DoctorMain from "./DoctorMain";
import DoctorSidebar from "./DoctorSidebar";

const DoctorShow = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DoctorSidebar />
      <DoctorMain />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DoctorShow;
```

Here DoctorShow not showing properly . If I show the component DocotorShow on my `App.js` then it is showing properly but when I am connecting through another Route file while logic is same ..what is the problem then please solve?
another mention to `DoctorMain` this component have other 6path connecting with `DoctorSidebar`
please check

Comment: Your code works correctly when I'm trying it in a codesandbox. Check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-lehmann-1p7hn?file=/src/MyShow.js

Answer (score 0):

Are you still facing the same issue?

I just tried to run your code locally but works fine. I'm leaving the code sample here. Let me if there is any difference

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-forked-gxv8j

Comment: thanks for trying..but I already done it thank you